# how to capture the time a field is updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller, model

I'm aware of updated_at and created_ate in rails.
But what I'm interested in is the ability to update a field within a model when another field is updated. Here's what I've tried:

in my model:

```
protected

  def update_email_sent_on_date
    if self.send_to_changed?
      self.date_email_delivered = DateTime.now
    end
  end
```

and in the one place in my code that updates the field in question:

```
  distribution.send(:update_email_sent_on_date)
```

the problem is, this doesn't seem to be doing anything to my db table at all. I even tried removed the check on "send_to" but still nothing.

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hey I think my original answer to your other question wasn't quite as clear as it should've been.  I've revised / improved the explanation.  Perhaps try re-reading it and making this method `private` instead of `protected`.  Then you won't have to use `send` to call the method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not saving it after you make the change.

Change the method to this:

```
def update_email_sent_on_date
  if send_to_changed?
    self.date_email_delivered = DateTime.now
    save
  end
end
```

Or save the model after calling it like so:

```
distribution.update_email_sent_on_date
distribution.save
```

Comment: Are you sure that `send_to_changed?` is evaluating to `true` in this case?  Perhaps try putting a test `puts` statement inside of the `if` block and then restarting your application and running it again and make sure that it's actually executing that block.

Comment: yeah that was the culprit. but why? what's the *right* way to use the _changed? method?

Comment: Check out the docs on `ActiveRecord::Dirty`: http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Dirty

Comment: If you wanted, you could condense the contents of the `update_email_sent_on_date` method to be this: `update_attribute(:date_email_delivered, DateTime.now) if send_to_changed?`.  The `update_attribute` method will update a single attribute and save the record.  http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attribute